# Slurm: compute node saves output only locally

Tags: ubuntu, installation, output, slurm

this is my first time installing `slurm` instead of using it, and I’m having two points that are not clear yet:
After trying many ways I got `slurm` (one controller and one computing node) finally working by following the instructions in this [tutorial (slurm part)](https://glmdev.medium.com/building-a-raspberry-pi-cluster-784f0df9afbd).

The first issue is that the compute node saves the output only locally. Switching the user manifests this issue as the compute node tries to find the directory given in `—-output` only locally.

The second issue is if I want to enable new user to use the cluster, should he be added to the slurm group?

I’m wondering how it is usually done? Does it work only by providing shared amount? Do I need to include the NFS part (in the mentioned tutorial) to get it working? I’m assuming because of the `munge` and passwordless ssh connection it is expected that the working directory will be the output dir unless it is set otherwise..right??

Apologies if it is an obvious issue, I hope you could kindly clarify what I‘m missing here.

Answer (score 1):

1. `—-output` will only write to the path mentioned or PWD. You need to use NFS in that scenario (This is the ideal way). Each user has their own directory in the NFS. From [slurm documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html) **The output file will be generated on the first node of the job allocation. Other than the batch script itself, Slurm does no movement of user files**
2. Yes you need to add the new user using `sacctmgr`. For example like this:

   sacctmgr create user name=USERNAME account=GROUP

You definitely need an NFS mount if you need to use multiple compute nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Regarding the user creation, I skiped the database part since it caused a lot of problems while installing. I'm still unsure, can't I just grant the users access to the controller node and they can submit the jobs this way? which brings me back to the first issue, i.e. why the compute node saves results locally only?

Comment: Yes, it is also possible like that (check for permissions etc while doing so). You can grant access to the controller node (or dedicating a particular user for slurm activities). There are different non-elegant ways to do it. Regarding the output, **the output file will be generated on the first node of the job allocation ([See here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html)). Other than the batch script itself, Slurm does no movement of user files**. So, if you want the file should be accessible from other nodes, it should be part of NFS.